# Android TranslateAnimation to specific position in pixels

Tags: android, animation, view

What I want to do is animate multiple views to a specific position, in PIXELS!
I am using a TranslateAnimation for that. I want to animate from the top left corner of the display, which is I believe x: 0 and y:0 to a variable position.

```
        private void drawGameField() {

            TextView [] tvs = new TextView[10];

            for(int i = 0; i < tvs.length; i++) {

                tvs[i] = new TextView(this);
                tvs[i].setX(i * 50);
                tvs[i].setY(i * 50);
                tvs[i].setText(i + "");

                gamelayout.addView(tvs[i]); // relativelayout that is created in the onCreate method
                animateObject(1000, tvs[i], 0, (int) tvs[i].getX(), 0, (int) tvs[i].getY());                
            }
        }

        private void animateObject(int time, TextView tv, int fromDeltaX, int toDeltaX, int fromDeltaY, int toDeltaY) {

            Log.i("Animation", "Animating to: x: " + toDeltaX + ", y: " + toDeltaY);
            TranslateAnimation t = new TranslateAnimation(fromDeltaX, toDeltaX, 
                                                            fromDeltaY, toDeltaY);

            t.setDuration(time);
            tv.startAnimation(t);   
        }
```

**My problem is, that die Animation is just not doing what it should do (the pixels the animation animates to do not match my input), why? What am I doing wrong?**

My Logcat output as you can see it in the animateObject Method is perfectly correct, the pixels match my desires.

LogCat output as follows:

```
Animation  Animating to: x: 0, y: 0 
Animation  Animating to: x: 50, y: 50 
Animation  Animating to: x: 100, y: 100 
Animation  Animating to: x: 150, y: 150 
Animation  Animating to: x: 200, y: 200 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the **ViewPropertyAnimator**.

The **translationX(...) and translationY(...)** methods exactly meet my desires.